# How to set a variable inside a gtk-rs closure?

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

I'm building a markdown app, and I want to keep two copies of the text, one a `source` text, and the other the `TextBuffer` with all the correct tags and such.

I need to set the contents of this source field inside a closure:

```
buffer.connect_begin_user_action(clone!(source => move |a| {
  let text = a.get_text(&a.get_start_iter(), &a.get_end_iter(), false).unwrap();
  source = text; // error: cannot assign to captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
```

An alternative might be to set some attribute on the `TextBuffer`, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Why do you think that usage of this library will change the semantics and rules of the rest of the language? Said another way, why do you think that it's important that gtk-rs is in use? Could this be closed as a duplicate of a hypothetical question that is "How to set a variable inside a Rust closure" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what to rename the question to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextBufferExt::connect_begin_user_action()` accepts `Fn`-closures, that is closures which can't change their captured environment. When you need to change something that can't be changed, you can use types with interior mutability, like `RefCell`.

If you'll adjust the type of `source` to `RefCell<String>` and change assignment inside closure to `*source.borrow_mut() = text;`, the code will compile, but there's another problem. You assign a value to the cloned `source`.

The macro `clone!` expands into

```
{
    let source = source.clone();
    move |a| {
       let text = // ...
       // ...
    }
}
```

That is, the closure captures and changes a copy of the variable `source`, not the original variable. `Rc` is one of the methods to do what you intended

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
// ...
let source = Rc::new(RefCell::new("Text".to_string()));
// ...
buffer.connect_begin_user_action(clone!(source => move |a| {
    let text = a.get_text(&a.get_start_iter(), &a.get_end_iter(), false).unwrap();
    *source.borrow_mut() = text;
    // ...
}));
```

Another method is removing `clone!` macro and capturing `source` by reference (you'll need to remove `move` before closure), but in this case it will not work as `connect_begin_user_action()` expects a closure with `'static` lifetime, that is a closure with no captured references to local variables.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was it!